# Calling a method after a delay without holding up existing threads

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, delay, actionevent

How can I use a timer to delay a calling a method once by a random time?

```
if(getDropPickup())
{
    Timer timer = new Timer(getDelayTime(), new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            collectItems();
        }
    });
    timer.setRepeats(false);
    timer.start();
}
```

When I try to do something like this I have problems with the timer constructor being undefined. What is the best way to call a method after an amount of time without delaying the main thread?

Comment: Use a Handler with postDelayed

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Thread` which uses `Thread.sleep()` so you wont block your main thread
while using the `sleep` method.

**sample:**

```
if(getDropPickup())
{
    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int delay = getDelayTime();
        Thread.sleep(delay);
        collectItems();         
    }
});

t.start();
}
```